# Converting years and months in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time, duration

I am working with time column like below:

```
import pandas as pd
 
# initialise data of lists.
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 
        'Time':['3 years 4 months in role 20 years in company', '1 year 7 months in role 2 years 2 months in company',
                '2 years 1 month in role 7 years 2 months in company', '3 months in role 8 years 2 months in company']}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
# Print the output.
df
```

I need to split the time column into two columns time_in_role(months) and time_in_company(months). And calculate the appropriate time in months.

Sample input:

[image]

Output expected:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Parse the time column data, it seems to me like it follows a pretty clear structure.

Comment: How to parse ? Could you help me to pre process this time column by splitting role and company in months entirely

Comment: Are you sure your expected output is correct? `Time_in_Company(months)` should be `240`as per your logic, why it is `120`?

Comment: Months is years x 12.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: @shaikmoeed it was typo I got the answer thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to get years/months from the string. Afterwards it's just simple math:

```py
role = (
    df["Time"]
    .str.extract(r"(?:(?P<y>\d+) years?)?\s*(?:(?P<m>\d+) months?)? in role")
    .astype(float)
    .fillna(0)
)

company = (
    df["Time"]
    .str.extract(r"(?:(?P<y>\d+) years?)?\s*(?:(?P<m>\d+) months?)? in company")
    .astype(float)
    .fillna(0)
)

df["Time_in_Role(months)"] = (role["y"] * 12 + role["m"]).astype(int)
df["Time_in_Company(months)"] = (company["y"] * 12 + company["m"]).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Name                                                 Time  Time_in_Role(months)  Time_in_Company(months)
0    Tom         3 years 4 months in role 20 years in company                    40                      240
1   nick  1 year 7 months in role 2 years 2 months in company                    19                       26
2  krish  2 years 1 month in role 7 years 2 months in company                    25                       86
3   jack         3 months in role 8 years 2 months in company                     3                       98
```